# Construction of angle bisector of a given angle

Tags: geometry

> Steps of Construction :
>
> 1. Taking B as centre and any radius, draw an arc to intersect the rays BA and BC,
>    say at E and D respectively [see Fig.11.1(i)].
> 2. Next, taking D and E as centres and with the radius more than
>    $\frac12$
>    DE, draw arcs to
>    intersect each other, say at F. $\tag{*}$
> 3. Draw the ray BF [see Fig.11.1(ii)]. This ray BF is the required bisector of the angle
>    ABC.
>    [image]
>    Fig. 11.1
>    Let us see how this method gives us the required angle bisector.
>    Join DF and EF.
>    In triangles BEF and BDF,
>
> BE = BD (Radii of the same arc)
>
> EF = DF (Arcs of equal radii)
>
> BF = BF (Common)
>
> Therefore, ΔBEF ≅ ΔBDF (SSS rule)
>
> [From](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/iemh111.pdf)

In the above construction, I have a doubt in (*), why is it remarked that the radius must be greater than $\frac12 $ DE?, secondly, when actually doing the constructions how do we measure the arc length DE only with straight edge and compass?

Sure, I could use the formula  for it but I feel that is a bit of cheating.

Comment: If it isn't $\geq\frac12\overline{DE}$, then the circles drawn around $D,E$ wouldn't intersect. There's no need for a formula, just calibrate your compass to span $\overline{DE}$, and then increase the span of the compass by some non-trivial amount.

Comment: I can't understand what is cheating if you are using formula? One can definitely use formula until restricted

Comment: It is referring to the line segment $DE$, not the arc length. It is because otherwise the two circles wouldn't intersect.

Comment: Oh right @dodoturkoz that makes more sense, fixied it now

Comment: @DonThousand ,dodoturkoz, sure, but how do we proof that is a sufficient conditio nfor circles intersecting

Comment: It's just a case of the triangle inequality. For any $3$ points, there exists circles centered at $2$ of them intersecting at the third.

Comment: I will gladly accept if you write that as an answer with a bit more detail on how triangle inequality was used @DonThousand

Comment: @Buraian Consider two points, and a line drawn such that all points on the line are equidistant from both points (this is a standard construction). Consider some radius larger than the distance between the points and the line. Draw circles centered at both points. Since there must be points on the line of distance equal to the radius to the point (distance from a point is a continuous function from the line to $\mathbb R$, apply the intermediate value theorem), the circles both must intersect the line. By symmetry, they must do so at the same points. This shows that the circles intersect.

Comment: Hmm fair, but you have brought in analysis tools. I like it personally but I am trying to understand this in the frame work of geometric ideas

Comment: Please do not change the question.

Comment: @miracle173 the question was changed before the answer

Answer (score 1):

The radius must be greater than $\frac{1}{2} DE$ because if we draw arc with radius less than that the arcs will not intersect. Try yourself. Remember $DE$ is length of the straight line between points D and E

A circle is $360$° all the way around; therefore, if you divide an arc's degree measure by $360$°, you find the fraction of the circle's circumference that the arc makes up. Then, if you multiply the length all the way around the circle (the circle's circumference) by that fraction, you get the length along the arc.

Edit: As you can see in question diagram we need one common point F where $EF=FD$. Now if we choose length less than $\frac{1}{2} DE$ then let $EF$ and $DF$ be the distance in line segment between E and D from F. Now $EF+DF=DE$ so as to intersect. However both of them are less than half of $DE$. Thus $EF+DE$ can't be $DE$ and thus our assumption that they will meet was false

Comment: Does this answer your question Buraian?

Comment: A straight edge is not a scale, huh? That would make essentially anything constructible. A $1^\circ$ angle is certainly not constructible

Comment: @DonThousand ya I realised it later after answering although now edited it. However thanks for the reply

Comment: Hi! Jitendra Singh , the second part of your answer was helpful but it was the same help I received from the comments on the post. The first part, yes I understood the idea, but I am trying to figure out how to arrive at a proof for that.

Comment: @Buraian good to know my second part helped you. For the first part first hope you have a compass and pencil and scale Draw a angle and use radius as less than 1/2 DE you will see they will not intersect however I will try to show the proof

Comment: How do you mean? You construct the set up then prove that it is what you want it to be by using euclid axioms and posulates as shown in post above

Comment: @Buraian check the edit Does that answer your question

Comment: I feel your answer is still incomplete, how do you claim the $EF+DF=DE$ for intersecting?

Comment: If EF+DF=DE that means there is 1 common point F where they have intersected. If this condition will never be fulfilled that means there is no common point which means they have not intersected @Buraian

Comment: that is working back from the conclusion. You have to show that  the sum is a sufficient condition for an intersection to exsist

Comment: So ya @Buraian how can you say that I am working back from condition? $EF+DF=DE$ then it will intersect because this length would be long enough to make a point intersecting

Comment: I am asking how do you know that is the right amount of length such that it is indeed intersecting

Comment: Okay take a triangle ABC and let there be an altitude AD on BC. We know BD+CD=BC because D lies on BC. If we think the opposite then since BD+DC is BC that means D is lying on BC @Buraian

Comment: True but here D is between BC, that is B, D and C are colinear. However in case here, E,D,F are not